# Is Mr. Bean an Alien?

Tags: mr-bean

There are a lot of speculations about how [Mr. Bean](http://www.mrbean.com/about) is an Alien (from outer-space).

I haven't been able to turn up anything definitive, except for this:

> However, later episodes showed Mr. Bean dropping from the night sky in a deserted London street against the backdrop of St Paul's Cathedral. At the end of episodes three and six he is also shown being sucked right back up into the sky in the respective background scenes (black scene in episode 3 and street scene in episode 6). **Atkinson has acknowledged that Bean "has a slightly alien aspect to him".** 
> <sup>*-http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mr._Bean#Characters_and_recurring_props.* [emphasis mine]</sup>

I would like to find a definitive answer to this, **Is Mr. Bean Alien?**

Answer (score 15):

From the same source as the question (the sentence before) I think it's clear that he probably isn't an alien:

> At the beginning of episode two onwards, Mr. Bean falls from the sky in a beam of light, accompanied by a choir singing Ecce homo qui est faba ("Behold the man who is a bean"), recorded by Southwark Cathedral Choir in 1990. These opening sequences were initially in black and white in episodes two and three, and were intended by the producers to show his status as an "ordinary man cast into the spotlight".
>
> -http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mr._Bean#Characters_and_recurring_props

To reinforce Faizan's point we do see him in the movie with a passport. In order to get a british passport you MUST provide official documentation [(birth/adoption certificates, naturalisation certificates etc)](https://www.gov.uk/apply-first-adult-passport/documents-you-must-send-with-your-application)

Even if we look at the quote you have used in the question:

> Atkinson has acknowledged that Bean "has a slightly alien aspect to him"

This to me says he is simply acknowledging he is human albeit a bit of an odd one.

Comment: Aliens, capable of interstellar travel. Im sure forging some documents are easy enough.

Answer (score 11):

Mr. Bean being an alien is more of a myth that it's creators unintentionally created because of the opening of the original TV series.

But in reality Mr. Bean is born English and not an alien, in the film [Bean: The Movie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bean_%28film%29), he visits America on his English passport.

In [Mr. Bean animated series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mr._Bean_%28animated_TV_series%29), one of the episode that I remember, he was taken by alien space ship where he met aliens, which looked like him. In the end of the episode 
he is sent back by the aliens similar to the opening scene. Which makes connection to the opening scene of the original TV series.

Comment: Aliens, capable of interstellar travel. Im sure forging some documents are easy enough.

Answer (score 1):

In the episode, Room 426, when he is checking into the hotel. There was a brief period he forgets what to fill in. So he copies the guy next to him, muttering, "British", in a ah-ha moment.

An alien forgetting what his supposed credentials should be.

I've been watching the series again lately, with this in mind. Maybe aliens throwing him down to earth for their social experiments? How Bean always finds himself in these situations

Comment: Is it answer or new question ?? @John can you rephrase atleast it so that it will sound like answer.